# How can I view a suggested edit from profile review activity?

Tags: support, review-queues

I was looking at one of the candidate moderator's review history, and there were a large number of "Reject"'s on one of their own SO answers:

```
2d  reviewed    Reject (Question title here)
```

The link takes me to an answer, where they are the author of the answer.

Does this mean someone edited the author's answer, the original author was notified and prompted with an opportunity to reject?

**Is there a way to view the proposed edit, the one which was rejected?**

Mainly, I'm curious if I can see what the proposed edits were, so I can form an opinion of whether the person has good judgement in this regard.  Sometimes when people moderate content they are the author of, they may show some bias in doing so.

Comment: Are those the regular anonymous spam edits one of my answers is getting? That post is now a [spam honeytrap](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3282960#3282960) used to block other spam edits each time a suggested edit to it is rejected. Yes, that answer receives a few each week, [since December](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6468983).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeh, once I realized the "Reject Some Title" was not one long link, but actually two different links, then I was able to see the suggested edit, and it was clear it was some robo spam. I kind of feel like something should be there to break up the two links so they are clearly not one long link.  I would use a | but I'm not familiar enough with the site's design conventions to know if that's a good suggestion.

Comment: If a downvoter cares to comment as to why they feel this a bad question, be my guest.

Comment: @AaronLS Give it a comment and delete it, no reason to answer. Martijin would still have been notified, and being able to see it in the deleted question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Self answers have been encouraged if one finds the answer themselves as a reference for others with the same problem.  Care to link documentation or meta post that determines otherwise?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I personally see no reason to delete this question- It's a good, on-topic question the OP just happened to figure out on his own. I'm sure, since this isn't a well-documented functionality, someone else will eventutally come looking for this information.

Comment: @Kendra Well, let's see what will happen over a while.

Comment: And a close vote for offtopic.  What about this is offtopic?  It is about the SE site.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: *"Problem that can no longer be reproduced"* because it was answered? **Give me a break.**

Comment: @Radiodef _Trivially answered_ might be the key.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's not what the close reason says.

Comment: @Radiodef The exact reason says: _"The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system **or to the circumstances affecting the asker** have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And the only way that can apply here is if the asker finding the answer renders it obsolete. Why would we close a question because it was answered? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Radiodef Well, I think the real answer was already given with _@Martijn_Pieters_'s comment. But, sounds a bit catch22 from my side I agree.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Martin's comment was posted at 2015-04-20 21:34:27Z, and my answer was posted 11 minutes **before** that at 2015-04-20 21:23:15Z

Comment: @AaronLS _"... and my answer was posted 11 minutes before that ..."_ Well, I don't see what difference this actually makes?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It makes a difference in that "was already given" is an inaccurate assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Well I realized about 30 seconds afterwards that the link for the "Reject" word is a different link from the question title next to it.  So clicking on the outcome such as "Reject" takes you to the suggested edit page.